# UILocalnotification not showing in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Maybe I'm missing something but as far as I can tell, I am doing this right. I am trying to schedule a local notification but it seems to never show. I run the app, then hit the home button. In 15 seconds, the badge updates to 1 but I never see an alert.

The code I have in my view controller's viewDidLoad is:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *targetDate = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:15]; //15 seconds
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = targetDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Body!";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Action!";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

If the app is running, I do indeed get a call to:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Any ideas? As far as I can tell, this is all being handled correctly.

Comment: Anything in notification settings for your app?

Comment: I checked and I do not even see my app listed. For local notifications, do I have to request permissions like you do with remote notifications?

Comment: That's what it was. I had to register for notifications.

Answer (score 4):

I found that I failed to register for notifications.

Adding this:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Solved my issue.